# Calculate square of number and store them in dw in assembly 8086 masm

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

I am trying to calculate the square of 5 using brute force, so I tried this but it does not store anything in `dw`and I define `dw` like this `result dw 2 dup(?)`

```
mov ax, 5
mov bx, 5
mov cx, 1
mov dx, ax
loop1:
 add ax, dx

 cmp bx, cx
 je endLoop

 add cx, 1
 jmp loop1

endLoop:
 mov result, ax
```

Comment: works for me, so you don't show the other important parts (rest of the code, how you assemble it, how you run it, and how you check what the memory contains) See [MCVE] and improve your question with critical information. (most likely you did not set `ds` to point to the correct segment where `result` has reserved memory, or you are simply looking at wrong memory area in debugger)

Comment: @Ped7g so my data segment contains this `data segment result dw 2 dup(?) 
 data ends` and i am trying to retrieve the result like this `lea si, result
inc si
mov dl, [si]
mov ah, 2h 
int 21h`

Comment: If you are producing EXE file, then you must set up `ds` register to point to the data segment. The `mov [result],ax` does implicitly use `ds:result` address, unless you override it by explicit segment prefix, like `mov es:[result],ax`, then you must set `es` correctly. Re-read your book/tutorial to see where it mentions setup of `ds` and how it suggests to do it. (also how segmentation of memory works in 16 bit real mode of 8086)

Comment: And you are retrieving zero byte of the result, and then you output it, which will probably produce nothing on screen... (the `dw 2 dup (?)` does reserve four bytes of memory / `mov result,ax` will write two bytes (25 and 0 = 16 bit "25" integer), and your "retrieve" code will hit that 0 byte (high 8 bits of the 16b integer) ).  ... BTW, by your question and these details it is obvious you don't use debugger to see yourself per-instruction, what is happening... you are wasting everyone's time by that, get some debugger and learn to use it, it's critical for ASM programming.

Comment: Also to output "25" on screen you have to write two characters... '2' and '5'. The BIOS and DOS services don't have any "print integer" service, so you can go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info and check the "multi-digit" paragraph for 16b code (you are this week only like fourth person asking for the same thing) (the most annoying part is, that you managed to post in the question everything what is correct about your code, and hide everything what is wrong about your code and how you operate, that's why you should next time post proper [MCVE])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> calculate the square of 5

### 5^2 = 25 but your code produces 30

Your loop does 5 additions in total (1x in the fallthrough and 4x in the jump back).
Since `AX` starts out with its original value, you get too much!

Either start `AX` at zero or do 1 iteration less:

```
 mov ax, 5
 mov bx, 5
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, ax
 XOR AX, AX   ; start at zero
loop1:
 add ax, dx

 cmp bx, cx
 je endLoop

 add cx, 1
 jmp loop1
```

-

```
 mov ax, 5
 mov bx, 5
 mov cx, 1+1  ; one iteration less
 mov dx, ax
loop1:
 add ax, dx

 cmp bx, cx
 je endLoop

 add cx, 1
 jmp loop1
```

> it does not store anything in `dw` and I define `dw` like this `result dw 2 dup(?)`

Make sure to setup `DS` with code like this:

```
mov ax, data    ; maybe you'll need 'mov ax, @data'
mov ds, ax
```

Try an alternative memory addressing using square brackets:

```
mov [result], ax
```

---

From comment:

> i am trying to retrieve the result like this
>   `lea si, result`
>   `inc si`
>   `mov dl, [si]`
>   `mov ah, 2h`
>   `int 21h`

Why do you fetch the second byte of the result? That will probably be plain zero.
Moreover the result has 2 digits, therefore you need to ouput 2 characters.

This is a solution from one of my other recent answers:

```
mov ax, [result]     ; AX=25
mov bl, 10
div bl               ; AL=2   AH=5
add ax, "00"         ; AL='2' AH='5'
mov dx, ax
mov ah, 02h
int 21h              ; Outputs the character in DL='2'
mov dl, dh
mov ah, 02h
int 21h              ; Outputs the character in DL='5'
```

Comment: thank you very much! I believe the problem was I didn't know how to output correctly. It was getting stored.